# iptables блокировка по mac для входящего/исходящего "интернет" трафика

Tags: iptables

доброго времени суток

Ситуация: есть локалка, и "между" локалкой и  инетом стоит шлюз, обеспечивающий dns,nat. Белый IP статичен. Форвард разрешен между интерфейсами.

Нужно: сделать запрет с помощью iptables по маку для исходящего и входящего *интернет* трафика (условно всего трафика что идет от "белого" статичного IP) к устройству имеющего соответствующий мак.

Общая политика все разрешено.

Прошу помощи т.к. не силен в iptables.

пробовал iptables -I INPUT -m mac --mac-source 33:33:33:33:33:33  -d 192.192.192.11 -j DROP  (не работает)

up: допускаю, что общее правило запрета должно быть в "сетке" PREROUTING, ибо фильтр может сработать сразу после снятия "НАТовского"  хидера с пакета и сравнения его с хэшем адресата в локалке (по существу nat'a и механизма учета "серых" адресов в стеке)

список правила на шлюзе

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 17M packets, 1966M bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1     1293 71064 fail2ban-ssh-ddos  tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh
2     1293 71064 fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh
3     1293 71064 fail2ban-ssh-ddos  tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh
4     1293 71064 fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh
5      93M   11G ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
6      93M   11G ufw-before-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
7      93M   11G ufw-after-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
8      93M   11G ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
9      93M   11G ufw-reject-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
10     93M   11G ufw-track-input  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
11   20093 1315K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
12       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth2   any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http-alt
13    1976  100K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpts:6881:6999

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 484M packets, 418G bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1    2835M 2399G ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
2    2835M 2399G ufw-before-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
3    2835M 2399G ufw-after-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
4    2835M 2399G ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
5    2835M 2399G ufw-reject-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
6    2835M 2399G ufw-track-forward  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
7      56M 8253M ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   eth2    anywhere             anywhere            
8     104M  127G ACCEPT     all  --  eth2   any     anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
9        0     0 REJECT     all  --  eth2   eth0    anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
10    1322 71311 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth2   any     anywhere             video-server         tcp dpt:http-alt
11   8832K 1479M ACCEPT     all  --  eth4   eth2    anywhere             anywhere            
12       0     0 REJECT     all  --  eth2   eth4    anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
13       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     192.168.0.1          anywhere             tcp dpts:6881:6889

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 17M packets, 23G bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1      92M  111G ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
2      92M  111G ufw-before-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
3      92M  111G ufw-after-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
4      92M  111G ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
5      92M  111G ufw-reject-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
6      92M  111G ufw-track-output  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
7     1971 78840 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp spts:6881:6999

Chain fail2ban-ssh (2 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1     2586  142K RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
2        0     0 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain fail2ban-ssh-ddos (2 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1     2586  142K RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
2        0     0 RETURN     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим на шлюзе есть два интерфейса eth0 ("белый" статический) и eth1 (смотрит в локальную сеть).

В локальной сети есть хост, которому надо запретить ходить через шлюз. Его mac-адрес 00:11:22:aa:bb:cc.

Запрет будет выглядеть так:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth1 -m mac --mac-source 00:11:22:aa:bb:cc -j REJECT
```

**Update**.

По хорошему посмотреть бы еще цепочку PREROUTING шлюза.

Но как вариант метода научного тыка, можно поставить правило  в цепочку FORWARD, запрещающее передачу пакетов с интерфейса, к которому подключено видеонаблюдение, на интерфейс с "интернетом", и вставить его 7-м по счету.

Как-то так:

```
iptables -I FORWARD 7 -i ethX -o ethY -m mac --mac-source 00:11:22:aa:bb:cc -j REJECT
```

Comment: полный запрет на хождение пакетов через шлюз для хоста не нужно. Хосту НУЖНА локальная сеть, ибо это клиент для скуда и макроскропа(видеонаблюдение), нужен ТОЛЬКО запрет на output/input трафик в интернет для этой машины. То есть общее правило - можешь ходить куда хочешь в рамках локалки а за ее пределы - нельзя.

Comment: @Spouk У вас весь трафик с этого хоста завернут через шлюз? И если, например, выключить шлюз, то хост перестанет видеть локалку? Покажите все ваши правила iptables шлюза.

Comment: да, хост через свитч завязан с интерфейсом на шлюзе. И да, если отрубить шлюз локалка "упадет".

Comment: @Spouk такая конфигурация конечно же меняет решение. Если ответ никто не напишет - в понедельник гляну подробности.

Comment: @Spouk добавил в апдейт.